# Why does Groovy replace java.lang.String.length() with size()?

Tags: java, string, groovy, jvm-languages

Wikipedia's [current article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Groovy_%28programming_language%29&oldid=667478169) about the Groovy programming language explains that "Most valid Java files are also valid Groovy files" and gives the following examples, first of Java code:

```
for (String it : new String[] {"Rod", "Carlos", "Chris"})
    if (it.length() <= 4)
        System.out.println(it);
```

Then the same in Groovy:

```
["Rod", "Carlos", "Chris"].findAll{it.size() <= 4}.each{println it}
```

Notice in the first example that we used the perfectly ordinary Java method, [java.lang.String.length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--). In the second example this method has been mysteriously replaced with a call to a method called `size()`. I have [verified](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) that the second example is valid Groovy code and has the correct behaviour.

`java.lang.String` does not have a method called `size()`. Groovy does not subclass `String` for its own purposes:

```
String s = ""
Class c = s.getClass()
println c.getName() // "java.lang.String"
```

nor does it somehow add extra methods to the `String` object:

```
// [...]
for (def method : c.getMethods()) {
    println method.getName()
}
// prints a whole bunch of method names, no "size"
```

and yet still this code somehow works:

```
// [...]
println s.size() // "0"
```

I can't find any Groovy documentation to explain this.

- Where does `size()` come from?
- Why does it not appear on the object?
- Why was it added?
- What was wrong with `length()` and why is it not preferred?
- What other extra methods have been added to `java.lang.String`?
- What about other standard classes?

Comment: Just a quick guess: Groovy might be using it's own [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29#Metaprogramming) for magic like this.

Comment: And [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#size%28java.lang.String%29) is where it comes from apparently. [Here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.html) you can see what other classes/methods are there.

Comment: "What was wrong with length()?" - I always felt that `length()` was not really consistent (much less `Array.length`!) while the collections API uses `size()`.

Comment: And it doesn't _"replace"_ length with size (as alluded to in the question), it adds a new `size` method, and `length` is still there

Comment: I assumed that `length()` had been replaced, because it doesn't make sense to have two methods which do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Apart from you could have a function which accepts a strong or a collection and does something based on its size without having to check what it is first

Comment: Neither size() nor length() are very consistent, really... they should be getSize() and getLength()... but String pre-dates the Bean spec, and Thou Shalt Not Change Old Java.

Answer (score 16):

Groovy adds lots of methods to strings and all sorts of other classes. All of the convenience methods are part of why Groovy is great.

`java.lang.String` implements `java.lang.CharSequence`, and that's where it gets all (most of) the magic from. [`size()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#size()), for example. Groovy adds a `size()` method to most objects that can have something you'd consider a size so that you can use a consistent method across the board. `length()` is still entirely valid, Groovy doesn't remove this.

To see some of the methods Groovy adds, check out the [GDK](http://www.groovy-lang.org/gdk.html), and particularly [CharSequence](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and [Collection](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the doc of the Groovy class [`StringGroovyMethods`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html), it gives simple explanations of how things work with Groovy.

> Static methods are used with the first parameter being the destination class, e.g.. public static String reverse(String self) provides a reverse() method for String.