# Creating array in groovy with variable size - Jmeter

Tags: arrays, groovy, jmeter

I use user defined variable for a loop.

In the loop I want to make HTTP request and to store response value at array, name of array is Password (example for password 'lkjslf789078897').
before the loop I created an array in groovy and tried to give him the size of the loop.
I got this problem that the size of the array is for some reason 51, while the variable $Loop_Number is 3.

** Another question is how to pass the empty password array to a sampler inside the loop.
all the purpose is to create an array that will contains all the passwords from the http requests.

```
def arr_length = vars.get('Loop_Number');
def Password = new String[vars.get('Loop_Number')];
System.out.println(" Password array length is:  " + Password.size());
System.out.println(" array length shoul be is:  " + arr_length);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's groovy [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433991/why-does-groovy-replace-java-lang-string-length-with-size), You are calling `size()` function of String object, groovy actually uses String `length()` when you calling `size()`. This function will not work in Java.

In your case the value 3:

```
 48 (0 in ASCII value) + 3 = 51.
```